# Searching with path pattern in ack is very slow

Tags: ack

I'm trying to use ack to search for `foo`, but only in all `Gemfile` files in the current directory and all subdirectories.

Searching in all files is crazy fast: `ack foo`

But this is awfully slow: `ack -g Gemfile | ack -x foo`

The latter command takes 25 seconds to return which makes it basically unusable.

Am I doing it wrong? How to I search for a term in specific files only (I know about `--ruby` and `--php` but sometimes you want to specify the pattern youself)

**UPDATE**

After reporting this issue in the Github project, a fix was added that speeds up the `-g` option with large codebases (https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/458).
It should be included in the next release (> 2.12).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running ack 2.x you can easily create a file type for Gemfile.

```
ack --type-add=gemfile:is:Gemfile --gemfile foo
```

If you do that a lot, you put the `--type-add=gemfile:is:Gemfile` in your .ackrc and then you can just say

```
ack --gemfile foo
```

---

As the ack author/maintainer, I'm a little concerned that your original pipeline takes so long, and if you had some time and would be willing to submit it as an issue, someone might be able to take a look at why that is.  https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't think I want to create a file type for Gemfile (unless it speeds up searching) since I often want to use the same pattern to search in different files, not just Gemfile. I will create an issue in Github though. :)

Comment: Based on the issue you created on GitHub at https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/458, and without any investigation on my part yet, I *do* think that the gemfile type will speed things up, because ack should just see the filename and say "Oh, OK, I don't need to check anything else".

Comment: Ok, let's work with the Github issue for now and I'll update this SO question when we have found a solution.